# fade in/fade out text in textbox using JQuery and fix button in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Question #1**: How do I fade in the text and fade out the text instead of just showing it in the textbox

**Question #2 [SOLVED]**: I would like to put some space between the button icon and the text but it's not working.
Example of button:

[image: image overlapping texts]

**UPDATE**:
`padding-left: 30px;` fixed the space issue.

html:

```
<input type="button" id="sv" value="          Score Viewer"></input>
<input type="button" id="pv" value="          Print Viewer"></input>
<input type="button" id="ev" value="          Exam Viewer"></input>
<br>
<input type=text id="tvinfo" value="" readonly size=50 />
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sv').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').val("View scores of exams already taken");
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').val("");
        }
    );
    $('#pv').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').val("View who printed the certificate");
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').val("");
        }
    );
    $('#ev').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').val("View who already took the exam");
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').val("");
        }
    );
});
```

CSS:

```
#sv {
    background: #ccc url(view.png) no-repeat top left;
    height: 53px;
    width: 186;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#pv {
    background: #ccc url(print.png) no-repeat top left;
    height: 53px;
    width: 186;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#ev {
    background: #ccc url(taken.png) no-repeat top left;
    height: 53px;
    width: 186;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/tfRed/ like that?

I just created a fake input box and fade in/out the opacity of the actual input box ,and used `.stop()` for faster hover in/out.

```
$(function() {
    $('#sv').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').stop().fadeTo(500,1).val("View scores of exams already taken");
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').stop().fadeTo(200,0, function() {$(this).val("");});
        }
    );
    $('#pv').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').stop().fadeTo(500,1).val("View who printed the certificate");
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').stop().fadeTo(200,0, function() {$(this).val("");});
        }
    );
    $('#ev').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').stop().fadeTo(500,1).val("View who already took the exam");
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').stop().fadeTo(200,0, function() {$(this).val("");});
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Part 2: add a padding to your buttons:

`padding-left:45px;`

Part 1:

This is a bit tricky. What I would do is animate the color of the input. Then on mouse out, revert the color. Now jquery by itself doesn't animate color, but you can use their `UI script` to solve this problem.

1. set default color of input to the same color of the background.
2. on hover animate the color to the desired color you want people to see (i chose black)
3. on mouse out animate the color back to the same color of the input
4. once the animation is complete, remove the value of the input

Check out the full code below:

```
<style type="text/css">

#sv {background: #ccc url(view.png) no-repeat top left;height: 53px;width: 186;cursor: pointer; padding-left:40px;}
#pv{background: #ccc url(print.png) no-repeat top left;height: 53px;width: 186;cursor: pointer; padding-left:40px;}
#ev{background: #ccc url(taken.png) no-repeat top left;height: 53px;width: 186;cursor: pointer; padding-left:40px;}
#tvinfo{color:#fff;}
</style>

<input type="button" id="sv" value="Score Viewer"></input>
<input type="button" id="pv" value="Print Viewer"></input>
<input type="button" id="ev" value="Exam Viewer"></input>
<br>
<p><input type="text" id="tvinfo" value="" readonly size=50 /></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#sv').hover(function () {

            $('#tvinfo').animate({color:'#000'}).val("View scores of exams already taken");
        },
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').animate({color:'#fff'},function(){
                $(this).val('');
            })
        }
    );
    $('#pv').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').animate({color:'#000'}).val("View who printed the certificate");
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').animate({color:'#fff'},function(){
                $(this).val('');
            })
        }
    );
    $('#ev').hover(
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').animate({color:'#000'}).val("View who already took the exam");
        }, 
        function () {
            $('#tvinfo').animate({color:'#fff'},function(){
                $(this).val('');
            })
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: AWESOME script, but one issue with the script is if I move the mouse fast enough, even if the mouse is over one of the buttons, the textbox is blank. OR if I move the cursor from one button to another.

Comment: you might need to use fast on your animation, when resorting back to the original color

Answer (score 0):

White space is ignored in HTML. To add extra white space use `&nbsp;`.

To fade in/out use the `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` functions

Comment: He needs padding, I believe.

Comment: `padding-left: 30px;` fixed the issue